# Limit number of installed apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store

My kids both have an android tablet. With parental control I can limit the apps type to PEGI 7 for example, which works fine.

But they then keep installing apps until the device is full, and then doesn't work properly anymore.

What I am looking for is an option to limit the number of apps installed at the same time. So I can set that to for example 30 or 50. If they then want to install a new one they first need to remove one.

With googling on this topic I find a lot about time management, but I already have an app to arrange that. So this is purely to set the maximum number of installed apps.

I hope someone has an idea how to achieve this, either by a setting in Android, or by a third party app.

Thanks!